# Smallest closed set of probability one on a Polish space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have a Polish space $\Theta$, let its Borel $\sigma$-algebra be denoted by $\mathcal{B}$ and let $\Pi$ be a probability measure on $(\Theta,\mathcal{B})$. I want to show that there exists a smallest closed set $F \subset \Theta$ such that $\Pi(F)=1$.

This is a property that is assumed in a course I am following, but I have no clue how to prove this on my own. Is there maybe a book or could someone help me with the proof of this fact? Thanks!

Comment: What about the intersection of all closed subsets of $\Theta$ satisfying $\Pi(F)=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious thing to do is to let $F$ be the intersection of all closed sets that have probability 1.  This is obviously closed, but since it's an uncountable intersection, it's not obvious that it has probability 1.

To fix this, we could look at the complement.  Let $U$ be the union of all open sets having probability 0.  Then we will have $F = U^c$.  Now $U$ is open but since it is an uncountable union, it's not obvious that it has probability 0.

But as a hint: Polish spaces are second countable.  You can use this fact to write $U$ as a *countable* union of open sets having probability 0.